# Issue in creating product "Brand" feature in cs cart using PHP API

Tags: php, curl, cs-cart

I am getting issue while creating "Brand" feature in cs cart using cs cart API.

I am using like below:

```
$URL= http://example.com/api/products/250

$data = '{"product_features": {"28": {"feature_type": "E", "value": "test"}}}';

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $URL);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$data);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$header);

// curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER,true);

$result=curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

 $re = json_decode($result,true);

  print_r($re);
```

getting "product_id" in response but no feature is adding. I have checked the feature id again and it is ok.
Please help me to sort the issue
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Working with products features in CS-Cart API is a little bit tricky, because they didn't provide enough documentation for it.

"Brand" is a feature with type "E" (Extended), each brand is different "variant", you should know "variant_id" of each brand, before you update it.

Here is a little example how your data should look.

```
$feature_id = 'ID_OF_BRAND_FEATURE';
$brand_id = 'VARIANT_ID_OF_YOUR_BRAND';

$product_data = [
    'status' => 'A' // Just some param when you update
];

$product_features = [
   $feature_id => [
       'feature_id' => $feature_id,
       'feature_type' => 'E',
       'variant_id' => $brand_id,
     ]
];

$product_data['product_features'] = $product_features;
```

You can use this CS-Cart API wrapper to make your life easier https://github.com/drahosistvan/cscartapi

Comment: Thanks, official docs are still mistakenly reporting 'value' instead of 'variant_id'

Comment: Do you know how to handle features with type "M"? `variant_id` has no effect on those :(